# Getting zipped XML files(accommodation.xml.zip) with curl PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, ftp

I have used and tried below code for getting the xml file from FTP server, Actually that xml file is zipped as accommodation.xml.zip.
So that I couldn't get that xml file using curl() in php

```
$url_method = "ftp://ftp.example.com/accommodation.xml.zip";
$username = "test";
$pwd = "test";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_method);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$pwd");    
   $xmlcontent = gzdecode ( curl_exec($ch) ); 
   curl_close($ch);
   print_r($xmlcontent);
```

By using this code, I have got below error:
//////////////////////////
Severity: Warning

Message: gzdecode(): data error

Filename: controllers/cron.php

Line Number: 438
/////////////////////////

But when I try to use the ftp url in browser, that zip file has downloaded.

Can anyone help me to get the xml file using curl() without error ?

Answer (score 1):

`gzdecode()` does not unzip files. It decodes different but similarly named files called gzip or gz files. This is why the function reports a `data error`.

You will have to use the [PHP Zip Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) instead to extract and read the XML files from the zip.
You can find use examples for the PHP Zip functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).

Comment: I want to print the xml content from zip file, can you tell me the exact function for extract & display the xml file from FTP server